# Finding offset from a code snippet

Tags: mips, cpu-architecture, mips32

I am a bit stuck up with the following question,

> Consider the following MIPS code and answer the questions that follow.

```
addi $t1, $s0, 400
loop: lw $s1, 0($s0)
add $s2, $s2, $s1
lw $s1, 4($s0)
add $s2, $s2, $s1
addi $s0, $s0, 8
bne $t1, $s0, loop
```

> What value is the label loop translated to in the conditional branch
>   instruction?

Now I know the mathematical formula for Branch Target Address. But here as memory addressing is not done so I found out the offset by counting the lines between the target address and PC. This gives the answer to be 7 (word offset). Am I right with this approach?

Comment: Really? Vladimir's answer chosen? Unbelievable...

Comment: @m0skit0: Yes, both of you were correct with the answers. He had mentioned PC+4 too.

Comment: I answered before him and more elaborate. Anyway np.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick experiment with MARS simulator http://courses.missouristate.edu/KenVollmar/MARS/download.htm gave me the answer-6, -5 for number of lines difference and another -1 because PC is increased by 1 after the instruction.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, I'm afraid not.

As MIPS instruction reference says:

> An 18-bit signed offset (the 16-bit offset field shifted left 2 bits)
>   is added to the address of the instruction following the branch (not
>   the branch itself), in the branch delay slot, to form a PC-relative
>   effective target address.

So as I understand, the distance from the branch instruction to the `loop` label is negative (because the label is **before** the branch, thus the address is lower). The distance is calculated in number of words (hence the 2 bits left shift). As all MIPS instructions are 4 bytes, this would be 6 instructions before, hence -6 is the value that should appear in the branch instruction offset (lower half-word). In binary: 1111 1111 1111 1010 (two's complement). In hexadecimal: FFFA.

Checked with simulator and seems that my reasoning is correct since the instruction is coded as 0x1530FFFA.

Comment: You were faster, just correction, 4 bytes, not bits is the width of the encoded instruction.